# ¿Por qué en el debug no toma en cuenta los cambios en el código después de Android Studio 3.3.2?

Tags: android, android-studio

Ayer actualicé a Android Studio 3.3.2 y estoy teniendo problemas con el debug.

Anteriormente cualquier mínimo cambio que hacía a la aplicación era asumido por el debug. Ahora hago cualquier cambio y no me lo asume, me sigue mostrando el código viejo.

He intentado lo siguiente y nada funciona:

- `Rebuild Projet`
- `Clean Projet`
- Provocar un cambio en el gradle y sincronizar
- Ejecutar `Invalidate Cache / Restart` en el menú `File`
- Reiniciar Android Studio
- Desinstalar la App y volverla a instalar

Nada de eso funciona.

> Lo único que hasta ahora me funciona es ejecutar la opción `Build
>   Bundle(s) / APK(s) > Build APK(s)` del menú `Build`. Al hacer eso
>   parece que me actualiza el archivo de debug que se instala cada vez en
>   el dispositivo cada vez que le doy a debuggear.

Pero no quiero cada vez tener que darle a esa opción y luego a debug.

Antes de la instalación de este nueva versión de Android Studio yo le daba al icono de debug y me reconocía todos los cambios. Incluso en compilaciones sin error podía hacer cambios y luego darle al botón amarillo con forma de rayo (`Apply changes`) y esos cambios eran reflejados. Ahora nada de eso funciona.

Esta es mi configuración de debug:

#### General

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

#### Misceláneo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

#### Debugger

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

#### Profiling

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguien sabe cómo hay que configurar el debug para que funcione como antes: que aplique los cambios con sólo darle al botón de Debug?

Comment: En que tipo de dispositivo lo has probado? me paso algo similar en un LG

Comment: @IgmerRodriguez es un RedMi de Xiaomi. Nunca me había dado problemas.

Comment: Y tienes instant run activado?

Comment: @IgmerRodriguez ahí tengo todas las casillas marcadas.

Comment: Prueba desabilitando instant run, `File -> Build,Execution,Deployment -> Instan Run -> `y quita el check de Enable Instan Run

Comment: Niente @IgmerRodriguez, sigue sin reconocer los cambios en el código. Antes tenía `Instant Run` activado y funcionaba. Además lo usaba mucho, cuando la app no hacía crash, podía cambiar cualquier cosa en el código y si le daba a `Instant Run` se ejecutaba teniendo en cuenta esos cambios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He encontrado la solución y la comparto aquí por si le sirve a alguien.

Son unos sencillos pasos:

1. Ir a la opción `Edit configurations` de `Run / Debug Configurations`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2. En esa pantalla buscar la opción `Before launch`, darle al signo de `+` y seleccionar `Gradle-aware Make`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

3. Se abrirá una ventana modal como esta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahí no hay que hacer nada, dice *Leave empty for no se qué*, pues eso dejarla vacía y presiona el botón `Ok`

4. Se pondrá la opción `Gradle-aware Make`  en la lista. Confirmar dándole a los botones `Apply` y luego `Ok` en la parte inferior derecha. La pantalla tiene quedar así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Eso es todo.